# How to add 2 or more views to one scrollView that relate with Page controll?

Tags: iphone

I'm new to iphone development. I used `UIPageControl` and `UIScrollView` where I wanted to add 2 or more views into a single `UIScrollView`. I have 2 pages of Page controls. Please give me an example or link for implementing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the `UIScrollView` you can add a number of `UIView`'s by simply displaying them in the scrollview.